# Getting the local URL in mvc/ Controller not recognising local url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I a trying to test the following code. This is a summarised code.

```
string url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(url))
        {
            return Redirect(url);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

In this code the url is obtained from context but in my original code it is passed to the controller action as string from a Authorize filter and looks like `http://localhost:53249/Products` in Debug.Write. However the `IF` is not satisfied that the url is local URL can someone explain what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you only need to chek for [HttpRequest.IsLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by using the following sentence

```
string url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the returnUrl to Url.IsLocalUrl() instead of the current request url context. 
Your passing invalid url to Url.IsLocalUrl().

Comment: that sentence is actually in the Filter and not in controller.